# An asymptotic statistics calculation

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, asymptotics

I have a question about an apparently routine asymptotic calculation.

Suppose that we have variables $X \in \mathbb{R}^{p}, Z \in \mathbb{R}^{q}, Y \in \mathbb{R}$. Write $E[Y \mid X] = f(X; \beta_0)$ and $E[Y^2 \mid X,Z] = g(X,Z; \gamma_0)$, where $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^s$ and $\gamma \in \mathbb{R}^{t}$ are unknown parameters. Assume $f$ and $g$ are continuous.

Suppose that we have $n$ i.i.d. samples of $X,Z,Y$ and that we use the data to construct $\sqrt{n}$-consistent estimators $\hat\beta_n$ and $\hat\gamma_n$ such that
\begin{equation*}
 \sqrt{n} ( \hat\beta_n - \beta_0 ) = O_p(1), \\
 \sqrt{n} ( \hat\gamma_n - \gamma_0 ) = O_p(1).
\end{equation*}

What can we say about the rate of convergence of the following term?
\begin{align*}
 & (P_n - P_0) \left[ \frac{f(X;\hat\beta_n) - f(X; \beta_0)}{g(X,Z;\hat\gamma_n)} \{ Y^2 - g(X,Z;\hat\gamma_n) \} \right] \\
=\, &  \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{f(X_i;\hat\beta_n) - f(X_i; \beta_0)}{g(X_i,Z_i;\hat\gamma_n)} \{ Y_i^2 - g(X_i,Z_i;\hat\gamma_n) \} - \mathbb{E}_{P_0} \left[ \frac{f(X;\hat\beta_n) - f(X; \beta_0)}{g(X,Z;\hat\gamma_n)} \{ Y^2 - g(X,Z;\hat\gamma_n) \} \middle| \hat\beta_n, \hat\gamma_n \right]
\end{align*}
where $P_n$ is the empirical expectation so that $P_n h(X,Z,Y) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n h(X_i,Z_i,Y_i)$ and $P_0$ is the expectation with respect to the true distribution so that $P_0 h(X,Z,Y) = E_{P_0} [h(X,Z,Y) \mid (X_1,Z_1,Y_1), \dots, (X_n,Z_n,Y_n)]$ is the expectation with respect to an independent copy of $(X,Z,Y)$, for any function $h$ which is data-dependent or not.

I believe the term is $o_p(n^{-1/2})$, but I don't know how to show it. I suspect the continuous mapping theorem is used to handle the $f$ and $g$ terms then the weak LLN is somehow used for the "$P_n$" term, but I don't know how to handle all the pieces. Please be as detailed as possible.

Comment: Usually one would describe $\hat\beta$ as $\sqrt{n}$-consistent if $\sqrt{n}(\hat\beta-\beta_0)=O_p(1)$ rather than $o_p(1)$ -- are you sure the conditions are the ones you want?

Comment: @ThomasLumley Thanks for pointing that out; I've updated the question. My goal is to have standard assumptions on $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\gamma$ and show that the "$P_n - P_0$" term can be ignored in a $\sqrt{n}$ analysis.

Comment: I don't see $f(X,Z;\hat\gamma)$ defined. Is that meant to be $g$ rather than $f$?

Comment: @ChristianHennig Yes, thank you for the correction

Comment: $P_n$ governs the distribution of the estimators $\hat\beta$ and $\hat\gamma$, but here these two estimators also appear in the $P_0$-expectation. This looks fishy to me. These need $n$ to be defined, but there's no $n$ in $P_0$.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I'm not sure what you mean. You can take $P_0$ expectations of statistics. For example, the expectation of the sample mean is the population mean.

Comment: @user551504 The expectation of the sample mean is the population mean *if you have an i.i.d. sample of size $n$* from $P_0$ (which is actually $P_n$). That's not a straight $P_0$-expectation, it's a $P_n$-expectation. Not sure what your notation is supposed to mean, but in Van der Vaart e.g. $P_0f=\int f dP_0$ (expectation over $P_0$); what's in $f$ cannot depend on $n$.

Comment: @ChristianHennig I've added an extended definition of $P_n$ and $P_0$ in the question. Hopefully it clears things up. If you have $X_1, \dots, X_n$ i.i.d. with finite first moment, then $P_0 X$ is their population mean and $P_n X$ is their sample mean. This is standard "empirical process" notation, but can seem unfamiliar.

Comment: @user551504 I do not believe this is standard notation. Your explanation of $P_0$ still suggests that $P_0$ refers to a single realisation, which I'd have thought is standard, rather than an i.i.d. sequence of length $n$, which it looks like you mean (but then the notation suggests this doesn't depend on $n$!?). Are you saying that within $E_{P_0}$, the $P_0$ governs the distribution of, say, $\hat\beta$, despite this also occurring outside that expectation?

Comment: OK, I may now understand what you mean. Within $E_{P_0}$, $\hat\beta$ is treated as fixed, but in fact you're interested in the distribution of the whole term, in which $\hat\beta$ is in fact random, right? So the $E_{P_0}$ is *conditional* on $\hat\beta$, which has its distribution defined outside $E_{P_0}$. Correct? (Same $\hat\gamma$.)

Comment: @ChristianHennig That's a fair summary; thanks for following up. More detail is in section 19.4 (page 279) of van der Vaart 1998: "The notation $P_0 \hat{f}_n(x)$ are abbreviations for the expectation of $x \mapsto \hat{f}_n(x; \omega)$ with $\omega$ fixed."